# i want to show a popup menu when there is a focus event occur on a Jtextfield,popup is generated but t is not over that textfield where it should be

Tags: java, swing

```
timePopUp.setPopupSize(100, 50);
timePopUp.setLocation(fieldName.getX(),fieldName.getY());
```

timePopUp is the name of variable of JPopupMenu

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the point to screen using `SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen` and see whether it helps.